# Recorded video is bugged . Good sound but video with green or purple line/bloky

Tags: java, android, video-encoding

Hey, im trying to use mediaRecorder but on emulator i can't normal tested it. In emulators ddms and app sayd me about "prepare failed" but when i try to run it on phone - all ok ( problem only when video recorded - than i can see bug with video (bloky/lines on screen)
I run my app on 2 device : 1 device recorded video and sound - but have on screen bloky/lines with random colors ( sound are ok), on other device - when click on start record : i have error...(and app crashed) i think there error is  "prepare failed" .
Anyone know what is that  and how to fix it ?

Regards,Peter.
p.s. sorry for my bad english, hope u understand me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android camera capture produces green and blocky video ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889579/android-camera-capture-produces-green-and-blocky-video)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is solved , was problem with emulator